# Elasticsearch: get a list of the terms that were matched in each result

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I get the list of terms that elasticsearch matched in each result? I know the highlight contains this but I want to get a list of the terms that were found without manually performing postprocessing on the highlight for each result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [named queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-named-queries-and-filters.html) with unique query for each term.

Search result will contain matched queries for each document in result.